# Enabling Firestore Persistence for React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React Native Firebase and I am trying to enable persistence for my app.

On my Android onCreate:

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
```

> For some reason when I am online and I kill my app and reopen, the
>   images seems to reload and it takes long to appear..If I turn the net
>   off they will come up instantly showing that the offline data actually
>   works.

How do I enable the persistence for the firestore so it will load the unchanged data from the cache instantly?

I saw the documentation which shows that I would need to add this code for the android:

```
FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
        .setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        .build();
db.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

but I have no idea how to integrate with the React Native Firebase as I am importing the **RNFirebaseFirestorePackage**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For react-native+firebase, one of my suggestion would be [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) which is bridging between JS and native framework.

Doing quick search, seems like you [cannot directly](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/firestore/reference/firestore) - [enable persistance](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/firestore/reference/firestore#Unsupported-Methods).

You need to do it through [Settings](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/firestore/reference/Settings).

Comment: I explained in my question that thats what I am using and that I have enabled it via settings, but thats not the solution as it will not work while online